# MySQL Group By - Top 3 rows and nth row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | UserID | Score  |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1    | 3      | 12     |
| 2    | 3      | 11     |
| 3    | 3      | 12     |
| 4    | 2      | 14     |
| 5    | 4      | 8      |
| 6    | 2      | 13     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

From this I want to top 3 scores from entire table and a top score from particular user

```
+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | UserID | Score  |
+------+--------+--------+
| 4    | 2      | 14     |
| 6    | 2      | 13     |
| 3    | 3      | 12     |
| 5    | 4      | 8      |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Is this something I can get done in a single query?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to solve any part of the problem yourself?

Comment: Hint: Use `UNION` to combine the 2 queries.

Comment: I was able to order them and fetch the top 3 but not the 4th row in desired table. I just used a simple `ORDER BY score` for that. Meanwhile thanks for editing the question!

Comment: Yep. UNION (and the judicious use of parentheses) is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spoiler alert ;)

```
(SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE UserID = 4 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: @Strawberry I've looked at it and thought about it and cannot work out why you edited in `id DESC` doesn't this just give MySQL extra work that's irrelevant to the task?

Comment: Because the OP wanted ids 4,6,3 and not 4,6,1

Comment: And how does `ORDER BY... id DESC` in any way affect the number of results returned?

Comment: Erm, it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean " 4,6,3 and not 4,6,1" just thought the OP cared about the "top 3 scores". Anyway, it's in the past now, will forget it and move on.

Comment: You say that likes it's some kind of wound against your conscience. It's just an edit to your answer. Feel free to roll-back if it pains you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

For certain definitions of "single query", sure... If you're willing to use sub queries or a union.

The best performance will probably come from two queries, but you can join them in a UNION for convenience if you wish.